# SQL - Get cost of goods sold using FIFO & LIFO

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the cost of goods sold so that I can later post it into the journal.
My stock-card table looks like this:

```
warehouse_product_id    sc_date         qty     price   reserved_qty    left_qty    status
3                       1/12/2014       2       100     0               2           debit
3                       2/12/2014       2       200     0               2           debit
3                       3/12/2014       10      200     0               10          debit
```

Let's say I want to `sell 3 items` with `warehouse_product_id = 3`, can anyone tell me how to query results below:

**FIFO (First-In-First-Out)**

```
warehouse_product_id    sc_date         qty     price   reserved_qty    left_qty    status
3                       1/12/2014       2       100     0               2           debit
3                       2/12/2014       2       200     0               2           debit
```

**LIFO (Last-In-First-Out)**

```
warehouse_product_id    sc_date         qty     price   reserved_qty    left_qty    status
3                       3/12/2014       10      200     0               10          debit
```

Another example, I want to `sell 5 items` with `warehouse_product_id = 3`, the resulted records should be like this:

**FIFO (First-In-First-Out)**

```
warehouse_product_id    sc_date         qty     price   reserved_qty    left_qty    status
3                       1/12/2014       2       100     0               2           debit
3                       2/12/2014       2       200     0               2           debit
3                       3/12/2014       10      200     0               10           debit
```

**LIFO (Last-In-First-Out)**

```
warehouse_product_id    sc_date         qty     price   reserved_qty    left_qty    status
3                       3/12/2014       10      200     0               10          debit
```

Question:

I want to get number of rows, that's if you sum up their `left_qty` it will be `>=` than the requested qty, which are `3 and 5` in above example. So by using FIFO, I would get the top 2 and 3 rows, respectively. For LIFO, I only need the last record since it's sufficient to cover the requested qty.

P.S. If possible I don't want to use a `Procedure`..

Comment: I am unclear what results you want.  Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully you can help @Gordon Linoff..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view with total sum of goods for each day:

```
sc_date       total_sum   reversed_total_sum
1/12/2014     2           14
2/12/2014     4           12
3/12/2014     14          10
```

Then you could easily select any amount of goods you need FIFO or LIFO.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see any benefit in LIFO. Because if you add a new record you simply have to update all previous records.

Comment: Yeah, there must be another field `reversed_total_sum` for LIFO

Comment: I think that view will be updated only when the table data is changed, so it won't be cost a lot of time.